# Get specific string from html table

Tags: javascript, html

how would I get just `Thu Dec 18 10:33:19 EST 2014` from the html below.

```
<div class="main">
<table border="1" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Thu Dec 18 10:33:19 EST 2014</td>
    <td class="meta">FitNesse Version: v20111026</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: By typing code...

Answer (score 1):

The CSS Selector is fairly simple to get the first `td` of the first 'tr' and then you can access the `innerText` to get the date text out of it:

```js
var text = document.querySelector('table tr:first-child td:first-child').innerText;
alert(text);
```

```html
<div class="main">
<table border="1" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Thu Dec 18 10:33:19 EST 2014</td>
    <td class="meta">FitNesse Version: v20111026</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: do u know how it would be if I wanted to use javascript only

Comment: @sxn102 - Already updated with vanilla javascript instead of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Pure JS.

```js
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
alert(tds[0].innerText);
```

```html
<div class="main">
<table border="1" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Thu Dec 18 10:33:19 EST 2014</td>
    <td class="meta">FitNesse Version: v20111026</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I assume you probably want a more general solution, but in that case you need to define exactly what you need to do better.

Comment: Probably will cause issues if you don't scope it in the div.

Comment: @mattfetz: almost certainly, but if the OP doesn't define the scope of the question, why should I worry about it?